# Show that the series $\sum_{k>r}^{N}\frac{(N-r)^{\frac{3}{2}(\frac{(N-r)+(N-k)}{N-r})}}{(k-r)^{\frac{3}{2}}(N-k)^{3}}$ is bounded for any $N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $r\ll N$. Show that the series given by,
$$\sum_{k>r}^{N}\frac{(N-r)^{\frac{3}{2}(\frac{(N-r)+(N-k)}{N-r})}}{(k-r)^{\frac{3}{2}}(N-k)^{3}},$$
is bounded for any $N$. This problem cropped up whilst I was studying log-correlated Gaussian fields:

1) http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~arguinlp/exposes/lecture2_cirm_2015.pdf (page 23)

2) http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00582v1.pdf (page 23)

The second paper suggested using an integral test, but I have had no luck. I have also tried comparison and evaluating a few of the summands but this hasn't shed any light either. Could anyone provide any hints as to how to go about this? Is an integral test the best way?